# Angular 2 and NodeJs - Calling NodeJs function with database connection variables from angular 2

Tags: node.js, angular

I am working on a project where the databse connection to MS SQL is being implemented in NodeJs function, lets say createDBConnection().
My frontend is Angular 2, so how can I effectively call the function createDBConnection() from Angular2 component.ts file?

Thanks

Comment: What does this have to do with Java?

Comment: You can't do that. Create a REST API to communicate with your backend.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Use Mssql in npm and using SQL SERVER and then try this, it worked for me :

```
    app.get('/table', function(request , response){
                var query = "select * from table";
                executeQuery (response, query);
});
    var  executeQuery = function(res, query){
     var conn = new sql.ConnectionPool(dbConfig);

conn.connect().then(function () {
    var request = new sql.Request(conn);
    request .query(query).then(function (recordset) {
        response.send(recordset);
        conn.close();
    })
    .catch(function (err) {
        console.log(err);
        conn.close();
    });        
})
.catch(function (err) {
    console.log(err);
});
```

Comment: the only reason I can see for marking this as an answer is just due to added code. Otherwise, @abhishek-singh explained the same thing a month ago.

Answer (score 1):

As [@n00dl3](https://stackoverflow.com/users/3633742/n00dl3) stated in the comments you should create a REST API for this.

Assuming you are using `express` with your `node.js`;

```
var app = express();

app.get('/test', function(req,res){ //example http request receiver
  return res.send(myTestVar);
});
```

will make your back-end receive a /test REST api, to call it from your front-end you use the http module like this:

```
this.http.get('/test')
     .subscribe((res)=>{
       console.log(res);
     });
```

You can check our documentation section for a full example on nodejs-express/Angular communication under "*Getting started with Angular 2 with node.js/expressjs backend (http example included)*". I couldn't paste the link since documentation section is deprecated now.

Answer (score 1):

Use [mssql](https://www.npmjs.com/package/mssql) npm module for NodeJS to connect your NodeJS application with MS SQL Server and create an endpoint on NodeJS application to handle all database related calls.
For example, send the required parameters from Angular 2 application in the HTTP request to NodeJS and use that in your **createDBConnection** function. Same with other calls.